# Как остановить foreground сервис и удалить ongoing уведомление с помощью addAction

Tags: java, android, service, android-service

У меня есть foreground сервис и ongoind уведомление. На уведомлении есть кнопка, с помощью которой надо закрыть и сам сервис и уведомление. Закрывать уведомление и сервис по отдельности я уже понял как, но мне нужно всё вместе... Как это сделать?

```
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
            Intent buttonIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ButtonReceiver.class);
            buttonIntent.putExtra("notificationId", mId);

            PendingIntent btPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, buttonIntent, 0);
            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getBaseContext());
            mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.icon)
                    .setContentTitle("someText")
                    .setContentText("someText")
                    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_close, "someText", btPendingIntent);
            mBuilder.setPriority(2);
            mBuilder.setOngoing(true);
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
            stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
            stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);

            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                    stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
// mId allows you to update the notification later on.
            mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(
                Constants.ACTION.STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
            mNotificationManager.cancel(mId);
            lm.removeUpdates(ll);
            stopSelf();
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

Comment: Т.е. у вас `mNotificationManager.cancel(mId); stopSelf();` не прибивает сервис и уведомление?.. Суть вашей проблемы пока что не очень ясна

Comment: Прибивает! Но это не очень удобно, так как для этого нужно будет открыть активити и нажать на кнопку. Хотелось бы грохнуть их через кнопку на уведомлении.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам надо прикрепить к вашей кнопке "закрыть" в уведомлении интент, который будет вызывать ваш сервис со значением в интенте так, чтобы он, сервис, закрыл его. Т.е. так же сделать как и по нажатию кнопки в активити. Как-то так:

```
Intent buttonIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SERVICE_CLASS_NAME.class);
buttonIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION);
PendingIntent btPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, buttonIntent, 0);
```

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло!!!

Comment: @niklas1987, пожалуйста) Если ответ на ваш вопрос решает заявленную в вопросе задачу то вы можете отметить его верным, нажав галочку слева от тела ответа и получить за это репутацию и ачивку)